# Calling an environment variable from a .xcconfig file in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to setup a GitHub repository for a project that will involve the use of an API Key. In order to keep that key a secret, I have decided to make a .xcconfig file with the API Key and add the .xcconfig file to my .gitignore. So far I have linked the file with my build settings for the app target. But I'm not actually sure how to go about calling the variable in my swift code. I know that there are environment variables within the Xcode build schemes, but I'm not sure how you would call them from there either. Is there some kind of framework that I need to call? Nothing online seems to be pointing to linking to the actual file itself.